# no robot visible in rviz for urdf tutorial

Tags: ros, rviz, urdf, tutorial, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working my way through the urdf tutorials, specifically [this one](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch)

On the first task it has me launch rviz to see the "r2d2" robot using the command:
roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=01-myfirst.urdf

I am in the proper directory, rviz launches just fine, but there is no robot visible. Just the grid map. This error appears under the Global Status in orange: No tf data. Actual error: Fixed Frame [map] does not exist

So I get that it's not getting transform data, but I'm not sure what to do about it. I have not modified any files, am running hydro on Precise.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/113561/no-robot-visible-in-rviz-for-urdf-tutorial/) by [richkappler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2694/richkappler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2013-12-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, so the idea was that this was fixed in the most recent commits to `urdf_tutorial` (see [urdf_tutorial/commit/8e0df6bc](https://github.com/ros/urdf_tutorial/commit/8e0df6bc39a9044bfd944b201aa3f5796c155c86)).

Apparently, the `CMakeLists.txt` install statement removes the directory prefix and installs the files into the package's `share` directory (ie: `$ROSDISTRO/share/urdf_tutorial`). The recent commits make RViz expect its config to be in `urdf_tutorials/urdf_tutorials`. The consequence of this is that RViz cannot find the configuration file and substitutes some defaults (which result in what you are seeing).

Short term work-around: remove the second `urdf_tutorial` from the last line in `display.launch`, so it reads:

```
<node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find urdf_tutorial)/urdf.rviz" required="true" />
```

Depending on how you installed the `urdf_tutorial` package, you might need to use `sudo` for this.

Long term solution: I've submitted a ticket to rectify this (again .. mea culpa): see [urdf_tutorial/issues/6](https://github.com/ros/urdf_tutorial/issues/6).

PS: the TF errors are ok for the `01-myfirst.urdf` file: it doesn't have any joints.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2013-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [richkappler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2694/richkappler/) on 2013-12-29**:
That did the trick, thanks!